# MobileVLCKit thumbnailer issue

Tags: ios, vlc

I want to create a `CVPixelBuffer`, since it need a `CGImageRef` I used `[VLCThumbnailer fetchThumbnail]` method and crashed with

> "Assertion failed: ([thumbnailer dataPointer] == *p_pixels), function
>   unlock, file
>   /Users/apple/opensource/vlc-ios/ImportedSources/VLCKit/Sources/VLCMediaThumbnailer.m,
>   line 74."  neither can I find the route"/Users/apple".

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(catchThumbnail) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];}

- (void)catchThumbnail {
if (self.vlcPlayer.hasVideoOut) {
    [self.thumbnailer fetchThumbnail];
}}

// VLCMediaThumbnailerDelegate
-(void)mediaThumbnailer:(VLCMediaThumbnailer *)mediaThumbnailer didFinishThumbnail:(CGImageRef)thumbnail {
NSLog(@"-----%@------",thumbnail);
```

}

worth mentioning: first time it logged :`MobileVLCKitPlayer[2736:1068033] -----<CGImage 0x7f803bed56e0>------,`but SECOND time crashed

Could someone help me,thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it, if somebody facing the same issue, remember to set `thumbnailer.thumbnail = nil` after handling it everytime :)